# cordova-plugin-ble-central autoconnect function always prompting user to pair the device

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, cordova-plugins, capacitor

I'm currently working on an ionic capacitor app that needs to connect automatically with a ble device.

I'm using the ble ionic native plugin:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ble
https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central

The goal is sending and receiving bluetooth info and commands to the ble device, which is a car alarm central that controls a few actions like lock and unlock the doors accordingly to the RSSI values on from the device.

So, I'm using the autoconnect function to auto-connect with the device as soon the device is close to range and all works perfectly in Android and iOS. The only issue is that everytime the device reachs the ble range and the ble plugin try connecting, the system prompts the user to accept pairing with the device again.

I need it to work without that pairing prompting everytime. I tried to pairing the device previous to initialize the app but it didn't worked as well. So is it a way to make this autoconnection work without prompting the pairing acceptance everytime it is disconnected?

The issue occurs on Android versions 9 and 10 and iOS.

I've changed my ble hardware interface to ask for a PIN code. I guessed the connection could be considered secure by the OS and prevent prompting the user to pair again. Didn't work as well.

Every connection started by the plugin seems like bounding and connecting as if it was the first time connecting to the device. Even connecting to a known device is prompt the user to input the PIN, which if not provided the OS forgets the device.

Any toughts? Anyone? Thank you!

Comment: You probably enabled encryption on at least one of your characteristics. If you do not need this you could disable it and pairing would no longer be necessary

Comment: Thank you for your response, @M.Kotzjan. The weirdest thing is that this ble module by default has no encryption on any characteristic. And connecting without using PIN code also makes the SO prompt the user to accept pairing to the device which already is a known device.